# Всегда ли безупречны наши классики

Tags: стилистика

**Можно ли критиковать классиков?** Вот, к примеру, повесть Л.Н. Толстого "Казаки". Современный писатель-фантаст Ю. Никитин берет отрывок из текста и показывает, как его можно отредактировать: "К примеру, ну куда на фиг столько "было"? Одежда его, а чья же еще? Сидит на нем, а на ком еще? 
**Прав ли он?** **Лучше стал текст?**

(1) Широкая черкеска была кое-где порвана, шапка была заломлена назад по-чеченски, ноговицы спущены ниже колен. Одежа его была небогатая, но она сидела на нем с тою особою казацкою щеголеватостью, которая состоит в подражании чеченским джигитам.

(2) Широкая черкеска  кое-где порвана, шапка была заломлена назад по-чеченски, ноговицы спущены ниже колен. Одежа  небогатая, но сидит  с тою особою казацкою щеголеватостью, которая состоит в подражании чеченским джигитам.

"Теперь картинка, которую видит герой, а не описание картинки" (Никитин). Мне тоже показалось, что в однообразное временное пространство в прошлом совсем неплохо вставить фрагмент из настоящего времени. Или не стоит этого делать?

Comment: Вера, второй текст - это редакция  Никитина?

Comment: Да, на первом месте авторский текст, а на втором - Никитина.

Comment: Второй текст сырой, слабый и неинтересный. В нем нет живости, да и смысл другой. В нем, как вы верно подметили, нет описания. Просто сообщаются факты.

Comment: Для точности эксперимента надо дать 2 отрывка и не говорить, где чей

Comment: Серж, но ведь Никитин предлагает особый художественный прием: взгляд на персонажа глазами героя, а не описание того, что увидел герой. Значит, текст стал хуже? Вы даете ему общую оценку, но она мне не очень ясна. Почему неинтересный, почему нет живости?  Если согласиться с вами, то я бы, скорее, могла сказать, что нарушена живая ткань произведения, появилось стилевое несоответствие.

Comment: Вера, а с какой стати он изменяет замысел автора?

Comment: В варианте Никитина излагаются факты... А это художественная литература. Текст должен быть живым... Для этого существует множество средств.

Comment: А у Никитина чем не художественная литература? Почему оне не живая? Я его не защищаю, просто пытаюсь понять. Вот у Достоевского, например,  широко применяется такой прием, как неявная прямая речь, мне он кажется очень выразительным.

Comment: Вера, я говорю только про данный отрывок.

Comment: Ни с его литературой, ни с ним я не знаком.

Comment: Все-таки у Толстого картина нагляднее.

Comment: Почитайте его книгу "Как стать писателем в наше время", 604 страницы!  Очень любопытная книжка, написана в виде коротких заметок на разные темы, читается очень легко. Для Никитина главное в литературе - это впечатление, как у импрессионистов. Его девиз: используйте все краски, все возможности, расцвечивайте свою языковую палитру, современная литература конкурирует с кино и телевидением, поэтому нужно писать ярче, интереснее, увлекательнее, чем классики. Нужно воздействовать всеми способами на воображение читателя.

Comment: Вера, его слова не совпадают на деле. Как видно из отрывка.

Comment: А у кого учиться писательскому мастерству? Учебники пишут люди, которые сами не писатели, а известные писатели-практики  не торопятся поделиться своими знаниями с новичками. А жизнь стала другой, и писать по-старому невозможно.

Comment: Вера, здесь я с вами согласен:другие времена - другой стиль. К сожалению, с современными писателями я не знаком. Но, наверное, существуют хорошие учебники, написанные не только лингвистами, но и литературоведами. Уверен, можно поискать в  интернете, в книжных магазинах.

Comment: Я встречал в интернете советы, как писать хорошо.

Comment: А кто советовал? Известные писатели? Тогда интересно было бы почитать. А то вот тот же Никитин пишет, что коллеги не приветствуют его откровенность в раскрытии приемов и секретов письма, это такая профессинальная тайна.

Comment: Не писатели. Это были учебники. Авторы лингвисты, литераторы. Т.е. там говорилось не как писать именно. Литературное редактирование. Какие ошибки часто допускают. Если смогу - пошлю вам ссылку. Наверное, года 2 - 3 назад читал. Не смог закончить. Тогда у меня не было интернета.

Answer (score 2):

У редактора от экономии на слове "было" вышла фантастическая смесь времён: черкеска порвана - при взгляде на него "сейчас", хотя шапка "была" заломлена - видимо, при более раннем взгляде. Можно было употребить это слово в самом начале - чтобы отнести его ко всему последующему, но никак не в середине. По общему же впечатлению от стиля, "выправленный" текст чем-то напоминает такой гипотетический пересказ: "На дубе была закреплена золотая цепь, по которой вокруг него круглосуточно ходил специально обученный кот..." С воображением мастера фантастического слова лучше было усмотреть отсутствие рифмы и попытаться "исправить" знаменитую нелюбовь Л. Толстого к стихотворным текстам :)

Изорвана была широкая черкеска

А шапку заломил назад он, как чечен.

Одёжа небогата - да, на вид известно...

И ноговицы спущены с колен.

Сидело всё на нём с щеголеватостью казацкой,

А оная, как видно, состоит

Во подражании огонь прошедшим адский -

Чеченский аж мерещился джигит.

Answer (score 1):

Эка невидаль — Льва Николаевича причесывать... Товарисч Никитин решил немного поломиться в открытую дверь? Но причесал-то довольно бездарно.

*...черкеска кое-где порвана, шапка была (???) заломлена...* Не нравится много "было"? Решил кое-где убрать, а кое-где оставить. Получилось куда как хорошо. Нет уж, надо оставить Толстого в покое, у него не стилистика главное.

Comment: Никитин с вами согласен. Он пишет, что у Толстого мысли гениальные и прозорливость поразительная, но вот язык неряшливый.

Comment: Лучше так, чем наоборот. Но тут Никитин выступает, опять же, в роли Капитана Очевидность.

Answer (score 0):

Извините, уважаемые коллеги, каюсь, "шапка была заломлена" - это моя ошибка, у Никитина просто "шапка заломлена", такой коротенький симпатичный текст, почему он никому не понравился?

"Широкая черкеска кое-где порвана, шапка  заломлена назад по-чеченски, ноговицы спущены ниже колен. Одежа небогатая, но сидит с тою особою казацкою щеголеватостью, которая состоит в подражании чеченским джигитам".

Кстати, я фантастику не много читаю, а вот книгу Никитина (название не помню) однажды купила и прочитала с большим интересом. Очень мне понравилась идея и сюжет был увлекательный, я потом долго пыталась найти продолжение романа, но так и не нашла. Но вот на чисто художественные достоинства книги как-то не обратила внимания.

Но в чем-то Никитин прав? Вот  нашел в тексте Шукшина такую фразу: "Он согласно кивнул головой". Два слова лишние!

Comment: Вера, но почему Никитин считает, что нужно вместо прошлого использовать настоящее у Толстого?

Comment: Наверное, он считает, что нужно наглядно изобразить то, что видит герой, чтобы читатель тоже взглянул на происходящее глазами героя,   для этого прошедшие события автор изображает происходящими в настоящий момент. Таким образом он воздействует на чувства читателя, а это для него главное, Читатель должен представить себя соучастником событий.

Comment: Вера, если Толстой изобразил картину в прошедшим времени, значит так нужно было по замыслу автора. Вмешиваться в авторский текст и говорить, что стиль у Толстого плохой, он не имеет права.

Comment: Свой стили есть у каждого писателя и у каждого времени. Как говорится в стихотворении А. Кушнера: "Крепко тесное объятье.
Время — кожа, а не платье.Глубока его печать.Словно с пальцев отпечатки,С нас — его черты и складки, Приглядевшись, можно взять.

Comment: Вы правы...!!!!

Comment: Повествование в настоящем времени - частный приём, который естественен для отступления в виде рассказа от имени персонажа, напр. при перечислении им недавних событий (иду я и вижу... а тут он набегает и...). Для статического же описания ранее виденного это не очень подходит. Можно литератору (при желании) заставить себя выдержать в таком стиле и целый роман, чтобы понравиться критикам новизной стиля. Но здесь-то зачем? Я вижу в этой попытке только обезличивание текста, написанного непринуждённо и языком своего времени.

Comment: Ну да, правильно, но Никитин не предлагает  редактировать Толстого, он на примере Толстого рассуждает о том, как писать современному писателю. Тогда в книжном магазине, пролистав вашу книжку, читатель примет решение купить ее  (или  скачать в Интернете). Это классикам было хорошо, а у нас писателей как (ну с разным можно сравнить).

Comment: Но не надо на примере классиков показывать, как писать.  У толстого со стилем все нормально.

Comment: Серж, вы уверены, что все с вами согласны. Критиков у Толстого никогда не было?

Comment: Вера, вот что нашел. Художественный стиль «Казаков» получил широкое признание даже среди критиков главной идеи. Кстати, наберите в поисковике "Язык и стиль Толстого'' и вы увидите, что как неправ Никитин.

Comment: >> **"Он согласно кивнул головой". Два слова лишние!** Ага, а в "видел своими собственными глазами" сколько лишних слов? И всё же мы так говорим. А Никитин, я не пойму, хочет писать дистиллированным языком, что ли? Так пусть пишет, кто не даёт... Но классики тут ни при чём.

Comment: «Из-под куста мне ландыш серебристый приветливо кивает головой.» Лермонтов. Конечно, можно сказать: "Он согласно кивнул. Но назвать это ошибкой уже нельзя". Таких узаконенных тавтологических повторов много.

Comment: Серж, ну ландыш-то тут при чем, это такое поэтическое сравнение,  здесь без головы уж никак не обойтись. Никитин не хочет "писать дистиллированным языком", он говорит о словах-сорняках, которые не приносят пользы нашему воображению, а только засоряют текст.